# PHP: Why when I print the contents of the session ignores the leading zero?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session

I've a problem when print the content session, because when create the session, the variable is string (varchar obtained from a mysql field):

Initial variable: 09680040

Print with alert or display in div: 9680040

???

```
PHP CODE

$query = "SELECT nombre, apellidop, apellidom, tUser FROM users WHERE ncontrol = '$numeroControl'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['n_control'] = $user['ncontrol'];
}

JS CODE
........
alert <?php echo $_SESSION['n_control'];?>;

JQuery CODE

('#div').html(<?php echo $_SESSION['n_control']; ?>);
```

**EDIT:** The problem is only when display alert, and when put content on div in jquery

Comment: In place of the three quesion marks, why don't you show some code?

Comment: Are you sure the value in the database is stored with the leading zero?

Comment: Is that really the JS code you're using? That doesn't exactly look valid...

Comment: Is the MySQL field of type int? That might be why

Comment: No, the type is varchar, the error only show when display alert or put content session in div!

Comment: @SoldierCorp Should be `alert(...);` (missing parentheses) and then there is still the issue that @YMMD explains in his answer.

Comment: Oh yeah @Niko, I forget it, but in original code i have! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
('#div').html(<?php echo $_SESSION['n_control']; ?>);
```

This produces the following line which is sent to your browser:

```
('#div').html(09680040);
```

This will be interpreted as an integer by your Javascript parser. Simply put quotes around it in order to make it a string:

```
('#div').html('<?php echo $_SESSION['n_control']; ?>');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) question. It has nothing to do with the [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/_SESSION) or [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) part.

In essence your final JS code will become:

```
alert 09680040;
```

Ignoring the obvious syntax error, Javascript will see that as numeric constant.

You'll have to create a Javascript string in your PHP code to keep all contents. Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
alert(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['n_control']);?>);
```

(Either way your description of the problem is incorrect, and the example code certainly isn't your actual code. So this is my guessing answer..)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $_SESSION['n_control'] = strval($user['ncontrol']);
```

Comment: It's the same, because the error cause when display alert or put content in div!